# Div with overflow: auto appears in front when transform rotate(90deg) applied

Tags: html, css

I have a div called `scrollable-container` that holds an empty header div, and its scrollable content. Then, I have a div `floating-button` in front of the `scrollable-container`.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="scrollable-container">
    <div id="header">I am Header</div>
    <div id="scrollable-content">...</div>
  </div>
  <div id="floating-button">Float</div>
</div>
```

See fiddle below:

[Normal appearance](https://jsfiddle.net/evkwan/x35cgod0/1/)

The float button currently overlaps both the `header` and `scrollable-content`, and is in front as expected because it has a higher z-index value than `scrollable-container`. Also, `scrollable-container` has its own stacking context, so its children should never be able to go in front of anything outside of the parent.

However, what is unexpected to me was that if I applied `transform: rotate(90deg)` on the `wrapper` div, then the div `scrollable-content` now appears in front of  `floating-button`!

[After transform rotate(90) applied](https://jsfiddle.net/evkwan/tj23L0za/11/)

Could anyone please point out to me why is it displaying as such when rotated 90deg?

If you look at the 2nd fiddle, notice how the floating button is still in front of the div `header`, which is expected, but only appears behind `scrollable-content`.

**EDIT:**

My original question asked if there were known methods to fix the issue such that any divs that was originally and intentionally placed in front of the scrollable-content could still appear in front even after rotated 90deg.

F.Muller has kindly provided some workarounds in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65071406/528896).

However, I would like to know why the div with property `overflow: auto` when inherits a `transform: rotate(90deg)` could superseded its parent's stacking context and appear in front of everything else that's supposed to have a z-index order higher than it.

Some interesting notes:

1. This happens in the latest versions of Chrome and Safari, untested on other browsers.
2. Interestingly, if you were to rotate `wrapper` to be 80deg, it would still display the `floating-button` in front correctly. Only when it reaches 90deg, it would disappear behind the `scrollable-content`.
3. After doing some experiments and also as pointed out by F.Muller in comments below, it does seem that removing `overflow: hidden` at the `wrapper` div can remedy the situation... but why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably ignoring the `z-index` because the overlay-elements are not child-elements of the parent container: `#scrollable-container`.

I kinda fixed it by setting the `z-index` of `#scrollable-container` to `-1`. It seems to be working just fine in `Firefox 83.0 (64-Bit)` and in `Chrome V. 87.0.4280.67` too, after the adjustments.

The `overflow: auto` property on the `#scrollable-content` and/or `overflow: hidden` property on the `#wrapper` element will cause this visual behaviour in `Chrome`.

**Edit**:
It might just help, if you apply `position: relative` on the wrapper element. Relative containers will setup a layered stack. And we have 3 children now - the content and the two overlays. See: Alternative II.

**Solution with negative z-index:**

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #E2DCDE;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#scrollable-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

#scrollable-content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

#front-overlay1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#front-overlay2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #B97375;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.row1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2D2D34;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.row2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #686878;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="scrollable-container">
      <div id="header">I am Header</div>
      <div id="scrollable-content">
        <div class="row1">Column 1</div>
        <div class="row2">Column 2</div>
        <div class="row1">Column 3</div>
        <div class="row2">Column 4</div>
        <div class="row1">Column 5</div>
        <div class="row2">Column 6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="front-overlay1"></div>
    <div id="front-overlay2"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Alternative (removed an overflow property):**

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #E2DCDE;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#scrollable-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#scrollable-content {
  height: 100%;
  /*overflow: auto;*/
}

#header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

#front-overlay1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#front-overlay2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #B97375;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.row1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2D2D34;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.row2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #686878;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="scrollable-container">
      <div id="header">I am Header</div>
      <div id="scrollable-content">
        <div class="row1">Column 1</div>
        <div class="row2">Column 2</div>
        <div class="row1">Column 3</div>
        <div class="row2">Column 4</div>
        <div class="row1">Column 5</div>
        <div class="row2">Column 6</div>
      </div>
      <div id="front-overlay1"></div>
      <div id="front-overlay2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Alternative II (position: relative on the wrapper)**

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #E2DCDE;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: 0;
}

#scrollable-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

#scrollable-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#front-overlay1, #front-overlay2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#front-overlay1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 2;
}

#front-overlay2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #B97375;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 3;
}

.row1,
.row2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.row1 {
  background-color: #2D2D34;
}

.row2 {
  background-color: #686878;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="scrollable-container">
    <div id="header">I am Header</div>
    <div id="scrollable-content">
      <div class="row1">Column 1</div>
      <div class="row2">Column 2</div>
      <div class="row1">Column 3</div>
      <div class="row2">Column 4</div>
      <div class="row1">Column 5</div>
      <div class="row2">Column 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="front-overlay1"></div>
  <div id="front-overlay2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt! If possible though I would like to avoid using negative zindex. The demo is a simplified version of my app. In reality i have a few layers underneath the div with scrollable content. I found that using negative zindex often messes with the scrollable view when I enable it for user to scroll as some layers might unintentionally go ontop hence blocking the scrolling.

Comment: @evkwan Hmm okay. What is the desired outcome? Why is the wrapper overflow hidden?

Comment: The wrapper has overflow:hidden just to ensure that all of its contents are clipped within its area. The desired outcome would be like https://jsfiddle.net/evkwan/hwvnzgeu/3/ but with the `transform: rotate(90deg)` applied without needing to use negative z-index if possible. But I am not sure if this the only way forward as well...

Comment: @evkwan I had also posted an alternative - would this work? Other than that I feel like this will be hard to do. The `overflow: auto` on the `#scrollable-content` seems to be responsible for the issue. You already cut off the overflow within the `#wrapper` anyway. If you don't want to scroll there, it should just work if you remove it there.

Comment: @evkwan I think the wrapper in this case needs to be `position: relative` because only inside a relative container you can have z-layers. See my "Alternative 2" this should do the trick. I had overlooked that before - mainly because I want to change as few lines as possible because of the integrity. But it is very important to know what your exact html code has to look like because the solutions can vary drastically, really.

Comment: thank you for your options. Your answer Alternative 2 does not work for me as I needed the area to still have `overflow:auto`. Imagine if I wanted to overlay a floating div in front of the scrollable area after `transform: rotate(90deg)`. I took the day and tried a few of them and in the end what eventually fixed my issues were a mix of using `zindex: -1` and `transform: translateZ(0)` to layers that I wanted to overlay on top of the scrollable area when transformed.

Comment: I will accept your answer as it did helped me (thank you again!), although I would be really interested to know why the does a div with `overflow:auto` get promoted to the front when I am sure it is contained inside a div of lower stacking context!

Comment: @evkwan Okay cool. Ikr. Sometimes it is quite a challenge to fix browser-related problems. Uhm for the stack ... well ... z-index is only supposed to be used inside relative containers (this will setup a proper z-index-stack). For the next issue it is better to post the full html/css code - it is impossible to foresee these details (I can only guess). Idk why the transformation did that, but browsers aren't bug free and they do things differently ... it used to be much worse back when we had to support IE. Standards grow now, but so do new features.

Comment: Thanks @F.Muller. My earlier examples are not very good as I was very focused on proving the problem rather than showing the kind of situation one might run into this problem. I have modified the fiddle examples slightly to show my intention of wanting a div to be in front of the scrollable content for whatever reason. I edited my question to see if anybody can explain if this is an expected behaviour that I missed somewhere. :)